# JavaFX webview capable of requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview

[Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe) says that almost every browser is capable of running the function `requestAnimationFrame` but it my application it just won't work. I now have limitated debug options. Bad, but yet helpful are `sysouts()`, since I don't have a console, my JavaScript is bound to a java class. Running this function:

```
function go() {
    java.alert("here");
    var ticksPerRender = 5;
    java.alert("here?");
    requestAnimationFrame(function render() {
        java.alert("here @ start");
        for (var i = 0; i < ticksPerRender; i++) {
            java.alert("here in loop");
            force.tick();
        }
        java.alert("update");
        link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        }).attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        }).attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        }).attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });
        java.alert("update done");
        gnodes.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
        java.alert("gnodes done");
        if (force.alpha() > 0) {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }
    })
    java.alert("here @ end");
}
```

prints me `here` and `here?` but nothing more. Should I invest more time in debuging or isn't it possible to use `requestAnimationFrame` in a JavaFX webview? Or do I even make such an obvious mistake I just can't see?

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091764, seems to be a known bug, does anybody now a workaround? I want to speed up my d3.js force layout with it.

Comment: Solution with cross browser compatibility is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112401/requestanimationframe-undefined-in-ios-uiwebview, works perfect, just insert the provided code in the answer in your .js